# Android retrieve duration of mp3 without MediaMetadataRetriever

Tags: java, android, mp3

To get the duration of an mp3 file, I use this code:

```
MediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new MediaMetadataRetriever();
retriever.setDataSource(audioFile.getAbsolutePath());
String duration = retriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_DURATION);
```

However, MediaMetadataRetriever requires api level 10. Is there a way to achieve the same for older api levels?

Answer (score 0):

Try [FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever](https://github.com/wseemann/FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever):

```
FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever retriever = new FFmpegMediaMetadataRetriever();
retriever.setDataSource(audioFile.getAbsolutePath());
String duration = retriever.extractMetadata(MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_DURATION);
```

Comment: Per the documentation: Supported formats (audio and video) are aac, flac, mp3, ogg, 3gp and more!